# Почему os.walk печатает одни и те же файлы и папки несколько раз?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловая-система

Есть код, который рекурсивно обходит директорию и печатает все пути в ней.

```
import os
 
def create_struct():
    dirlst = os.walk(f'/home/dart/Загрузки')
    for (root, dirs, files) in dirlst:
        for dir in dirs:
            print(os.path.join(dir, root))
        for file in files:
            print(os.path.join(file, root))
 
create_struct()
```

Почему-то этот код несколько раз печатает одни и те же файлы и папки, а также само название директории, которую он обходит.

```
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки
/home/dart/Загрузки

/home/dart/Загрузки/khcp
/home/dart/Загрузки/khcp
/home/dart/Загрузки/khcp
/home/dart/Загрузки/khcp
/home/dart/Загрузки/khcp/api
/home/dart/Загрузки/khcp/api
/home/dart/Загрузки/khcp/api
/home/dart/Загрузки/khcp/api
```

Версия Python: 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно соблюдать порядок параметров в [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'/home/dart/Загрузки'):
    for dir_name in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, dir_name))

    for file_name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, file_name))
```

---

Повторение ошибки в вопросе:

```
import os

dir_name = r'C:\drive\my'
file_name = 'foo.txt'

print(os.path.join(dir_name, file_name))  # C:\drive\my\foo.txt
print(os.path.join(file_name, dir_name))  # C:\drive\my
```